# eliminar VARIAS LÍNEAS DE TEXTO en una misma celda en Excel

Tags: excel

Buen día

Quisiera saber como eliminar (masivamente) espacios en blanco de un texto de varias líneas en UNA única celda de excel, como se puede ver a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y que me quede de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: El texto donde está, en un fichero de texto, en un pdf, en otras celdas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTA:** La solución que propongo la he probado con **LibreOffice Calc**, y aunque no dispongo de una suite de Microsoft para probarlo en el mismo entorno, los pasos y resultado deberían servir, **aunque no puedo garantizar que vaya a ser el caso.**

Aunque esto solo es una deducción en base a las imágenes, los espacios en blanco que comentas parecen ser saltos de linea dentro de una celda.

Esto se puede conseguir presionando `Ctrl+Intro` para continuar escribiendo en una nueva linea en la misma celda, mientras que `Intro` terminaría la edición.

[image: Reproducción del problema descrito a modo de ejemplo]

En la imagen de arriba he reproducido el problema que planteas, lo que da soporte a la idea de que son saltos de linea en una misma celda.

La solución es utilizar la función de buscar y reemplazar, en el menu de edición.

[image: Diálogo de buscar y reemplazar]

**IMPORTANTE:** ha de marcarse la casilla `Expresiones regulares`, pues es lo que vamos a utilizar.

`\n` significa salto de linea

En el campo **Reemplazar** basta con poner un espacio en blanco.

Al presionar **Reemplazar todo** se sustituirán todos los saltos de linea por espacios en blanco, dejando los contenidos de todas las celdas en una sola linea.

[image: Resultado de la solución propuesta]

Es aconsejable que pruebes esto primero con un archivo de prueba y hagas una copia del archivo con el que vas a trabajar, por si sucede algún imprevisto.

Por muy útiles que puedan ser las expresiones regulares, hay que manejarlas con cautela, ya que de lo contrario puede haber resultados inesperados.

Comment: Wow muchisimas gracias, fue tal cual lo que necesitaba

En excel no se logró no me daba todas las opciones, pero a la hora de subirlo a google sheets fue tal cual como dijiste

De nuevo muchas gracias!